# Can Instabug and HockeyApp run simultaneously within an iOS/Android App

Tags: android, ios, hockeyapp, instabug

The Title states the question.

Wondering if these two crash reporting software entities are able to run simultaneously.

Comment: Not really, since only one will be called when en exception is thrown. Since you can only register one exception handler.

Comment: @rckoenes that's what I figured.. Not sure why I received the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

There should no problems in using another crash reporting tool with Instabug for an Android app.
However, we don't recommend using another crash reporting tool for your iOS app with Instabug, as it's not 100% guaranteed that Instabug will catch the crash in this case.